# Average value of vector in C using mpi

Tags: c, mpi

Hello friends i am currently working on a C project for my university class. What i am trying to do is find the average value of a vector, however i need to do that by using mpi.
I written some code but vor some reason the average value that i get is zero

consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int my_rank;
    int plithos_dierg, k, res, finres, num;
    int source, target;
    int tag1 = 50, tag2 = 60, tag3 = 70;
    int plithos;
    float data[100], mesi_timh = 0, m, f1;
    float data_loc[100];
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &plithos_dierg);

    if (my_rank == 0) {

        printf("Dwse to PLITHOS twn stoixeiwn tou dianhsmatos \n");
        scanf("%d", &plithos);
        printf("Dwse ta stoixeia tou dianhsmatos \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < plithos; i++) {
            printf("Dwse to %d noumero \n", i);
            scanf("%f", &data[i]);
            //mesi_timh=mesi_timh + data[i];
        }
        for (target = 1; target < plithos_dierg; target++) {
            MPI_Send(&plithos, 1, MPI_INT, target, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            num = plithos / plithos_dierg; //posous arithmous h kathe diergasia.
            k = num;
        }

        for (target = 1; target < plithos_dierg; target++) {
            MPI_Send(&data[k], num, MPI_FLOAT, target, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            k += num;
        }
        for (k = 0; k < num; k++)
            data_loc[k] = data[k];
    }
    else {
        MPI_Recv(&plithos, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        num = plithos / plithos_dierg;
        MPI_Recv(&data_loc[0], num, MPI_INT, 0, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    res = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < num; k++) {
        res = res + (data_loc[k]);
        printf(" mesa sto for %d \n", res);
    }
    // f1=res/plithos;
    //printf("mesi timi m %f",f1);

    if (my_rank != 0) {
        printf("prin to mpi send %d \n", res);
        MPI_Send(&res, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else {

        printf("\n Apotelesma of process %d: %d\n", my_rank, res);
        finres = res;
        for (source = 1; source < plithos_dierg; source++) {
            MPI_Recv(&res, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            printf("\n Apotelesma of process %d: %d\n", source, res);
            finres = finres + res;
        }
        /*
     printf("\n DIANHSMA:[ ");
    for(int i=0;i<plithos;i++) {
      printf("%f",data[i]);
      printf(", ");
      }
     printf("] ");*/
        printf("to plithos einai %d \n", plithos);
        printf("to final result einai %f \n", finres);
        printf("\n\n\n H MESH TIMH TOY DIANHSMATOS EINAI: %f\n", finres / plithos);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n H MESH TIMH TOY DIANHSMATOS EINAI: %f\n", finres / plithos);
    MPI_Finalize();
    // printf("\n\n\n H MESH TIMH TOY DIANHSMATOS EINAI: %f\n", finres/plithos);
}
```

At some point i noticed that when i try to print the vector instead of zero i get the last number of the vector as my final result. I am a newbie in mpi programming so please forgive my mistakes

thanks in advance!

Comment: `printf("\n\n\n H MESH TIMH TOY DIANHSMATOS EINAI: %f\n", finres / plithos);` ==> `printf("\n\n\n H MESH TIMH TOY DIANHSMATOS EINAI: %f\n", (double)finres / plithos);`. `int / int` results in an `int`.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn a few collectives: `MPI_Bcast()`, `MPI_Scatterv()` and `MPI_Reduce()`

Comment: @mch That worked thanks friend, I forgot about typecasting, makes sence now that i look at it